# vcenter location of matplotlib pcolormesh with TwoSlopeNorm

Tags: python, matplotlib

If I make a pcolormesh plot with a diverging colormap and TwoSlopeNorm to keep 0 in the middle of the colormap (because `vmax > abs(vmin)`), the location of `vcenter` changes between matplotlib version 3.4.3 to 3.5.2. An example code is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import colors

fld = np.random.random((10,10)) - 0.2

norm = colors.TwoSlopeNorm(vmin=-0.2, vcenter=0, vmax=0.8)

plt.pcolormesh(fld, norm=norm, cmap='bwr')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

With matplotlib 3.4.3, the ticks remain equally spaced between `vmin` and `vmax` ([matplotlib 3.4.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kcIg.png). However, with matplotlib 3.5.2 `vcenter` is forced to be the middle of the colorbar ([matplotlib 3.5.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OCVI.png)), so that the tick spacing between `vmin` and `vcenter` is different than the spacing between `vcenter` and `vmax`. What can I do with matplotlib 3.5.2 to keep the tick spacing constant, instead of forcing `vcenter` to be the middle of the colorbar. Essentially, how to get the result of matplotlib 3.5.2 to look as matplotlib 3.4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a non-linear Norm, so the colorbar has a non-linear scale (consistent with, for instance a `LogNorm`).  The old behaviour can be retrieved by setting the colorbar axes to be linear:

```py
...
cb = plt.colorbar()
cb.ax.set_yscale('linear')
...
```